# how to get the date value in drupal 8

Tags: 8

On submitting a form getting error as

Error: Call to a member function format() on null.

Here is the function:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) { 
  $exp_date = $form_state->getValue('expire_date')->format('H:i:s'); 
}
```

Comment: try `\Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($form_state->getValue('expire_date'), 'H:i:s');`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @awm in the comment you have to use the [DateFormatter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21DateFormatter.php/class/DateFormatter/8.5.x) service. But the [format()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21DateFormatter.php/function/DateFormatter%3A%3Aformat/8.5.x) method needs a timestamp so you can use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to parse the value:

```
$exp_date = \Drupal::service('date.formatter')
  ->format(strtotime($form_state->getValue('expire_date')), 'H:i:s');
```

Comment: I doubt that will help, `$form_state->getValue('expire_date')` is NULL according to the error message

Comment: Can you show us what `var_dump($form_state->getValues())` print please ?